# Aframe orbit-controls rotate object around its center while keeping other objects fixated

Tags: three.js, aframe

I am trying to rotate a box around its center while keeping the rest of the models fixated. Here is my code -

```
<head>
  <title>My A-Frame Scene</title>
  <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.8.2/aframe.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-orbit-controls@1.0.0/dist/aframe-orbit-controls.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-supercraft-loader@1.1.3/dist/aframe-supercraft-loader.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <a-scene>
    <a-entity id="super" supercraft-loader="name: better-reaction" ></a-entity>

    <a-entity camera look-controls orbit-controls="target: 0 1.6 -0.5; minDistance: 0.5; maxDistance: 180; initialPosition: 0 5 15">
        <a-box position="0 1.6 -21" color="red"></a-box>
    </a-entity>
  </a-scene>

</body>
```

and here is the codepen: https://codepen.io/nirajupadhyay11/pen/RBBpbd

However, the entire model rotates on dragging the mouse, instead of just the box.

The result I am after is keeping the box and the model fixated at their respective positions but when the mouse is dragged, the box should rotate around it's center.

I am trying to get this to work so that, in my game that I am developing, I can have a 3d gun model point to different directions based on mouse drag. Their are other 3d models in the game such as trees and rocks but they should remain in their position when the mouse is dragged.

Here is one example of what I am trying to achieve - https://codepen.io/jordizle/pen/haIdo

Could you please help me with this?

Thanks,
Niraj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The orbit controls are basically a camera rotating around on an orbit. Hence the name.

If you want the scene "still" and only one object rotating, you can't rotate the whole camera. You need to rotate the object alone.

A simple way to achieve what you want would be checking where the mouse is dragged on the window

1. when the mouse is pressed, get the position
2. on mousemove check how much the position has changed. Rotate the object accordingly to the changes.
3. when its released, stop listening for the mousemove.